# Ember.js set model data for {{render}} helper

Tags: ember.js, architecture

I'm trying to build a view that is going to display multiple models and aggregated data.

[image]

After doing some reading in the docs, the [`{{render}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) helper is probably the right way to build a view like this. For setting the model normally I'd just set up a Route in which I pass the needed model data:

```
App.BuildingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
         return this.store.find('buildings', '1');
    }
});
```

But if I include a template via the `{{render}}` helper, the route is not called. I'd like to know how I can pass the different models for each `{{render}}` helper independently form each other, including first filtering the model?

Comment: What changes to model?  If it's a user action then I would probably put the logic in a controller's action handler.

Comment: No I meant the initial model loading on page creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may be relevant:

In your BuildingsRoute you can have all of the required logic to return all relevant models e.g.:

```
App.BuildingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
         var self = this;
         return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                new Em.RSVP.hash({
                    building: self.store.find('building', params.buildingId),
                    clients: self.store.find('client'),
                    products: self.store.find('product')
                }).then(function (results) {
                   resolve({
                       building: results.building,
                       prods: results.broducts,
                       clients: results.clients,
                       foo: "bar"                            
                   });
                });
          }
  });
```

See [promises](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) for more info on how to structure and chain these.

Then in your view you can access these models as follows:

```
{{render 'products' products}}
```

or

```
{{#each product in products}}
   {{render 'product' product}}
{{/each}}
```